# APK's package name must be in the following format "com.example.myapp". It may contain letters (a-z), numbers, and underscores (_)

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, google-play, android-install-apk

I got this error while uploading apk to playstore.

Your APK's package name must be in the following format "com.example.myapp". It may contain letters (a-z), numbers, and underscores (_). It must start with a lowercase character.

I created apk in eclipse   ( file -> export -> export android application )

I have attached packag structures of the application and the manifest file. please help me out .

Thanks

[image]

Comment: The answer is in your question: _It must start with a lowercase character._

Comment: Thanks for reply !!

so what do you say should I change all packages to lower case like ?
app.orderbuzz    app.orderbuzz.cache   app.orderbuzz.domain ??? like that ?

pls let me know

Comment: Yes, that should fix it. I'm not sure if capital letters are allowed in the middle of a name, but since you already have to rename them, better make it all-lowercase. It's the standard.

Answer (score 1):

> Your APK's package name must be in the following format
>   "com.example.myapp". It may contain letters (a-z), numbers, and
>   underscores (_). It must start with a lowercase character.

Your package name should be in lowercase characters. Uppercase characters are not allowed.